# Parse mailer daemons, failure notices

Tags: python, email, parsing

I have something like 1500 mail messages in eml format and I want to parse them na get e-mail addresses that caused error and error message (or code).
I would like to try to do it in python.

Someone have any idea how to do that except parsing line by line and searching for line and error code (or know software to do that)?
I see nothing about errors in mail headers which is sad.

Answer (score 0):

So you have 1500 .eml files and want to identify mails from mailer-daemons and which adress caused the mailer-daemon message?

Just iterate over the files, then check the from: line and see if it is a mailer-daemon message, and then get the adress that caused the error out of the text.

There is no other way than iterating over them line by line.